# AxesLabel broken in Version 10 for 3D plots?

Tags: plotting, version-10

In version 10.0.1 (Win7), `AxesLabel` with arbitrary text strings works as expected in 2D plots:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)"}]
```

[image]

In prior versions the same worked for 3D plots as well; but not anymore in v. 10:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x - 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]]
```

[image]

Is this a bug? And is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: You can add a third dummy element in `AxesLabel` (e.g. `{"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)", ""}`). I think it is a small bug.

Comment: @ybeltukov Thank you; didn't think of trying that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me expand my comment. As I wrote, you can write

```
AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)", ""}
```

One label also works fine

```
AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)"}
```

But two labels doesn't work

```
AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)"}
```

Unfortunately it is equivalent to `AxesLabel -> Automatic`. The problem is in the definition of `` Visualization`Utilities`AxesLabelQ ``

```
Visualization`Utilities`AxesLabelQ[#, 3] & /@ {{"x"}, {"x", "y"}, {"x", "y", "z"}}
```

> {True, False, True}

You can repair it by the following command

```
Unprotect[Visualization`Utilities`AxesLabelQ];
Visualization`Utilities`AxesLabelQ[{_?
     Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`axislabelTokenQ, _?
     Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`axislabelTokenQ}, 
   Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`n_: 3] /; 
  Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`n === 3 := True
Protect[Visualization`Utilities`AxesLabelQ];
```

Now everything works as desired

```
Plot3D[Sin[x - 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious as to what you used to find this function?

Comment: @rcollyer just `??` and `ClearAttributes[..., ReadProtected]` for `Plot3D` and some nested functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are bugs within bugs. Consider this sequence:

**V9**

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"

```
Plot3D[Sin[x - 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)"},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Sin[x - 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)", Automatic},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]]
```

[image]

**V10**

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

```
Plot3D[Sin[x - 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)"},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large],
 PlotTheme -> "Classic",
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Sin[x - 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 AxesLabel -> {"Range (km)", "Velocity (m/sec)", Automatic},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large],
 PlotTheme -> "Classic",
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Well, I accept and welcome that **V10** requires the third `Automatic` - parameter. I am, however, hesitant to accept that blue turns to black and that classic isn't classic anymore.